# Массовые крэши приложения после увеличения minSdkVersion при обновлении

Tags: android, gradle

Пользователи массово жалуются на то, что после обновления из Play Марект приложение перестало запускаться (запускается и тут же вылетает). Однако если приложение полностью удалить и заново установить из Play Маркет, оно нормально работает.

В последнем обновлении потребовалось поднять `minSdkVersion` с `16` до `21`.

В build.gradle следующее:

```
buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21 /*было 16*/
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
```

Видим кучу вот таких сбоев:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.decodeHeaderAsJavaNetCookies (JavaNetCookieJar.java:91)
  at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.loadForRequest (JavaNetCookieJar.java:74)
  at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer.loadForRequest (ReactCookieJarContainer.java:44)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.kt:75)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
  at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain (RealCall.kt:194)
  at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run (RealCall.kt:138)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Что мы сделали неправильно? И почему после полного удаления и чистой установки приложение начинает работать?

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть: https://github.com/plaid/react-native-plaid-link-sdk/issues/28

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, это помогло, спасибо! Остался вопрос, почему так происходит? А произошло следующее: используются 2 модуля, A и B, оба тянут зависимость от модуля C. Модуль A зависит от модуля C версии 3, а модуль B от версии 4. И модуль B был добавлен в последнем релизе, что и привело к проблеме. После обновления приложение рушится с java.lang.NoSuchMethodError, а после чистой установки работает корректно. Получается, что при обновлении как-то патчится старя версия приложения и модуль C не обновляется. Если сделать зависимость от модуля С (версии 4) прямой, то приложение обновляется корректно.

Comment: Почему так происходит - идей нет)

Comment: Аналогично ))))